# How to add a scrollTo position into a function current function correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, position, scrollto

I am trying to add a scroll to a position on a page into some javascript but not quite sure how to go about this.

The code I have, basically allows me to click a link on a homepage which then will take you to another page and open the corresponding tab. The issue was part of the tabs ID was dynamically generated, anyway this fixes the problem but I want the page to scroll down to the general area at least where the tabs are on the page, doesn't have to be right to them.

```
$j(window).load(function () {
    $j("a[href^=" + window.location.hash + "]").click();
    window.location.href = window.location.href;
});
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your question is noct that clear: in YOUR page you have some links and the corresponding tabs in the same page: when the user clicks aone of this link, the corresponding page is than shown on YOUR page in the corresponding tab?

Answer (score 1):

The tab container' content here is dynamically generated (non-dom), just to simulate a close situation. You may mean hardcoded with php or any server-side language...

The script runs on page loading, it checks for the targeted tabs container (*here the div with the classname* `'.tabcontainer'`) and shows the tab that has the same Id found in the url. For example here : **thispage.html#nav-profile**

```js
//This function takes the target element (el) as parameter
function scrtoTabs(el) {
    $(window).scrollTop(el.offset().top).scrollLeft(el.offset().left);
}

$(window).on("load",function(){

$('.tabcontainer').append('<nav>  <div class="nav nav-tabs" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">    <a class="nav-item nav-link active" id="nav-home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-home" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>    <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>    <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-contact" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-contact" aria-selected="false">Contact</a>  </div></nav><div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-home-tab">Sint sit mollit irure quis est nostrud cillum consequat Lorem esse do quis dolor esse fugiat sunt do. Eu ex commodo veniam Lorem aliquip laborum occaecat qui Lorem esse mollit dolore anim cupidatat. Deserunt officia id Lorem nostrud aute id commodo elit eiusmod enim irure amet eiusmod qui reprehenderit nostrud tempor. Fugiat ipsum excepteur in aliqua non et quis aliquip ad irure in labore cillum elit enim. Consequat aliquip incididunt ipsum et minim laborum laborum laborum et cillum labore. Deserunt adipisicing cillum id nulla minim nostrud labore eiusmod et amet. Laboris consequat consequat commodo non ut non aliquip reprehenderit nulla anim occaecat. Sunt sit ullamco reprehenderit irure ea ullamco Lorem aute nostrud magna.</div>  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-profile-tab">Sint sit mollit irure quis est nostrud cillum consequat Lorem esse do quis dolor esse fugiat sunt do. Eu ex commodo veniam Lorem aliquip laborum occaecat qui Lorem esse mollit dolore anim cupidatat. Deserunt officia id Lorem nostrud aute id commodo elit eiusmod enim irure amet eiusmod qui reprehenderit nostrud tempor. Fugiat ipsum excepteur in aliqua non et quis aliquip ad irure in labore cillum elit enim. Consequat aliquip incididunt ipsum et minim laborum laborum laborum et cillum labore. Deserunt adipisicing cillum id nulla minim nostrud labore eiusmod et amet. Laboris consequat consequat commodo non ut non aliquip reprehenderit nulla anim occaecat. Sunt sit ullamco reprehenderit irure ea ullamco Lorem aute nostrud magna.</div>  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-contact-tab">Sint sit mollit irure quis est nostrud cillum consequat Lorem esse do quis dolor esse fugiat sunt do. Eu ex commodo veniam Lorem aliquip laborum occaecat qui Lorem esse mollit dolore anim cupidatat. Deserunt officia id Lorem nostrud aute id commodo elit eiusmod enim irure amet eiusmod qui reprehenderit nostrud tempor. Fugiat ipsum excepteur in aliqua non et quis aliquip ad irure in labore cillum elit enim. Consequat aliquip incididunt ipsum et minim laborum laborum laborum et cillum labore. Deserunt adipisicing cillum id nulla minim nostrud labore eiusmod et amet. Laboris consequat consequat commodo non ut non aliquip reprehenderit nulla anim occaecat. Sunt sit ullamco reprehenderit irure ea ullamco Lorem aute nostrud magna.</div></div>');

scrtoTabs($('.tabcontainer'));

//Here we check for which nav id is being mentioned in the url to load it as default active
var url = document.location.toString();
if (url.match('#')) {
    $('.nav-tabs a[href="#' + url.split('#')[1] + '"]').tab('show');
} 
});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="toptext">
<p>Lorem Ipsum ist ein einfacher Demo-Text für die Print- und Schriftindustrie. Lorem Ipsum ist in der Industrie bereits der Standard Demo-Text seit 1500, als ein unbekannter Schriftsteller eine Hand voll Wörter nahm und diese durcheinander warf um ein Musterbuch zu erstellen. Es hat nicht nur 5 Jahrhunderte überlebt, sondern auch in Spruch in die elektronische Schriftbearbeitung geschafft (bemerke, nahezu unverändert). Bekannt wurde es 1960, mit dem erscheinen von "Letraset", welches Passagen von Lorem Ipsum enhielt, so wie Desktop Software wie "Aldus PageMaker"</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum ist ein einfacher Demo-Text für die Print- und Schriftindustrie. Lorem Ipsum ist in der Industrie bereits der Standard Demo-Text seit 1500, als ein unbekannter Schriftsteller eine Hand voll Wörter nahm und diese durcheinander warf um ein Musterbuch zu erstellen. Es hat nicht nur 5 Jahrhunderte überlebt, sondern auch in Spruch in die elektronische Schriftbearbeitung geschafft (bemerke, nahezu unverändert). Bekannt wurde es 1960, mit dem erscheinen von "Letraset", welches Passagen von Lorem Ipsum enhielt, so wie Desktop Software wie "Aldus PageMaker"</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum ist ein einfacher Demo-Text für die Print- und Schriftindustrie. Lorem Ipsum ist in der Industrie bereits der Standard Demo-Text seit 1500, als ein unbekannter Schriftsteller eine Hand voll Wörter nahm und diese durcheinander warf um ein Musterbuch zu erstellen. Es hat nicht nur 5 Jahrhunderte überlebt, sondern auch in Spruch in die elektronische Schriftbearbeitung geschafft (bemerke, nahezu unverändert). Bekannt wurde es 1960, mit dem erscheinen von "Letraset", welches Passagen von Lorem Ipsum enhielt, so wie Desktop Software wie "Aldus PageMaker"</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum ist ein einfacher Demo-Text für die Print- und Schriftindustrie. Lorem Ipsum ist in der Industrie bereits der Standard Demo-Text seit 1500, als ein unbekannter Schriftsteller eine Hand voll Wörter nahm und diese durcheinander warf um ein Musterbuch zu erstellen. Es hat nicht nur 5 Jahrhunderte überlebt, sondern auch in Spruch in die elektronische Schriftbearbeitung geschafft (bemerke, nahezu unverändert). Bekannt wurde es 1960, mit dem erscheinen von "Letraset", welches Passagen von Lorem Ipsum enhielt, so wie Desktop Software wie "Aldus PageMaker"</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum ist ein einfacher Demo-Text für die Print- und Schriftindustrie. Lorem Ipsum ist in der Industrie bereits der Standard Demo-Text seit 1500, als ein unbekannter Schriftsteller eine Hand voll Wörter nahm und diese durcheinander warf um ein Musterbuch zu erstellen. Es hat nicht nur 5 Jahrhunderte überlebt, sondern auch in Spruch in die elektronische Schriftbearbeitung geschafft (bemerke, nahezu unverändert). Bekannt wurde es 1960, mit dem erscheinen von "Letraset", welches Passagen von Lorem Ipsum enhielt, so wie Desktop Software wie "Aldus PageMaker"</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum ist ein einfacher Demo-Text für die Print- und Schriftindustrie. Lorem Ipsum ist in der Industrie bereits der Standard Demo-Text seit 1500, als ein unbekannter Schriftsteller eine Hand voll Wörter nahm und diese durcheinander warf um ein Musterbuch zu erstellen. Es hat nicht nur 5 Jahrhunderte überlebt, sondern auch in Spruch in die elektronische Schriftbearbeitung geschafft (bemerke, nahezu unverändert). Bekannt wurde es 1960, mit dem erscheinen von "Letraset", welches Passagen von Lorem Ipsum enhielt, so wie Desktop Software wie "Aldus PageMaker"</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum ist ein einfacher Demo-Text für die Print- und Schriftindustrie. Lorem Ipsum ist in der Industrie bereits der Standard Demo-Text seit 1500, als ein unbekannter Schriftsteller eine Hand voll Wörter nahm und diese durcheinander warf um ein Musterbuch zu erstellen. Es hat nicht nur 5 Jahrhunderte überlebt, sondern auch in Spruch in die elektronische Schriftbearbeitung geschafft (bemerke, nahezu unverändert). Bekannt wurde es 1960, mit dem erscheinen von "Letraset", welches Passagen von Lorem Ipsum enhielt, so wie Desktop Software wie "Aldus PageMaker"</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum ist ein einfacher Demo-Text für die Print- und Schriftindustrie. Lorem Ipsum ist in der Industrie bereits der Standard Demo-Text seit 1500, als ein unbekannter Schriftsteller eine Hand voll Wörter nahm und diese durcheinander warf um ein Musterbuch zu erstellen. Es hat nicht nur 5 Jahrhunderte überlebt, sondern auch in Spruch in die elektronische Schriftbearbeitung geschafft (bemerke, nahezu unverändert). Bekannt wurde es 1960, mit dem erscheinen von "Letraset", welches Passagen von Lorem Ipsum enhielt, so wie Desktop Software wie "Aldus PageMaker"</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum ist ein einfacher Demo-Text für die Print- und Schriftindustrie. Lorem Ipsum ist in der Industrie bereits der Standard Demo-Text seit 1500, als ein unbekannter Schriftsteller eine Hand voll Wörter nahm und diese durcheinander warf um ein Musterbuch zu erstellen. Es hat nicht nur 5 Jahrhunderte überlebt, sondern auch in Spruch in die elektronische Schriftbearbeitung geschafft (bemerke, nahezu unverändert). Bekannt wurde es 1960, mit dem erscheinen von "Letraset", welches Passagen von Lorem Ipsum enhielt, so wie Desktop Software wie "Aldus PageMaker"</p>
</div>
<div class="tabcontainer">

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Any idea how I would work a ScrollTo into the function that i already have?

Comment: You didn't share with us your HTML part :) Either those tabs IDs are being generated by php or with javascript. The code I'm showing here works... We don't know if you are using bootstrap or not... If it's another script that handles tabs visibility... usually it's an active class that you need to toggle. So please explain the missing part that we are supposed to imagine :)

Answer (score 0):

you will need to know some kind of anchor/element close to the element. You can either call the `window.scrollTo(x,y)` function with approximate x/y coords or by selecting the element (`document.querySelector('.classNameOfYourAnchor')`) and using the [element.scrollTo()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTo) function

Comment: So I put an anchor on the row that the tabs are in and then this is what the Javascript would look like?

   $j(window).load(function() {
      $j("a[href^=" +  window.location.hash +"]").click();
      window.location.href = window.location.href ; 
      element.scrollTo.document.querySelector(#whats-on');
});

This along the right lines?

Comment: you want the scrollTo to happen __on__ the page you want to scroll and __after__ the page has loaded. You dont need to add a new anchor. You can also just select the div/table/whatever parent element of your tabs

Comment: Ok any on advice on how that script would look?

Answer (score 0):

If you are fine with using vanilla JavaScript, you could use the [`Element.scrollIntoView()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) method to achieve that.

Assuming the element selected by `"a[href^=" + window.location.hash + "]"` links to to an element with the id `window.location.hash` minus the #, `document.getElementById(window.location.hash.slice(1)).scrollIntoView();` would move that element into view.

In case you were still using `a` tags where the `name` attribute holds the identifying string, an equivalent line would go like this: `document.querySelector('a[name="' + window.location.hash.slice(1) +'"]').scrollIntoView();`